# How can I display constantly updating text on opencv window?

Tags: python, opencv, apriltags

I'm working on a project with april tags and a computer vision system to detect them from a webcam. I have a good system as of now that prints the data to the terminal but I would like to display this numerical/text data on top of the video window or in another window. I've already tried using `cv2.putText()` but that only puts static text on the page and it can't be updated in real time like I want. This is my code that tries to update a window in real time with the number of tags detected in the webcam video. But it ends up just writing a `1` for example and I can't figure out a way to erase that text and update it.

Is this even possible in OpenCV? Or is there another way?

```
while True:
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    detections, dimg = detector.detect(gray, return_image=True)
    print(detections)

    num_detections = len(detections)
    # print('Detected {} tags.\n'.format(num_detections))
    num_detections_string = str(num_detections)


    overlay = frame // 2 + dimg[:, :, None] // 2

    clear_text = ''
    text = checkNumDetections(num_detections, num_detections_string)
    
    cv2.putText(whiteBackground, clear_text, (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 10, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(whiteBackground, text, (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 10, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow(window, overlay)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.imshow(dataWindow, whiteBackground)

    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: you cant "erase" anything really. better make a fresh `whiteBackground` for any frame in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-initialise the 'whiteBackground' image in each loop, before you draw anything on it.

I know this will work, but it will give you a black background:

```
whiteBackground = np.zeros((columns, rows, channels), dtype = "uint8")
```

This should work to give you a white background, but experiment and see:

```
whiteBackground = np.full((columns, rows, channels), 255, dtype = "uint8")
```

I usually work with opencv in c++, so I'm not 100% sure of the exact syntax, but that should work.